# Empty files response from GitHub compare API

Tags: github, github-api

I'm getting inconsistent responses by using the GitHub API to compare two commits. Sometimes it returns fine, sometimes I get a response that includes all of the right information, except for an empty `"files":[]` section.

It seems to only come back incorrectly when it's comparing commits from master rather than another branch created from master. That's the only pattern I've detected with it so far.

When I use a browser to compare the commits, it's displaying all of the right files there. And I'm only comparing two commits that were back to back, so it's not like it's hitting the 250 commit limit to compare between.

Any idea why the GitHub API wouldn't include the files section properly every time?

Comment: Do you mean Github API ? Gitlab ? Azure DevOps ?

Comment: I meant Github API

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I was storing the previous commit ID in a file when running on any branch, but that caused problems when the branches weren't the same. So when it ran on the same branch twice in a row, it was fine because the comparison between the two commit IDs were in the same branch. But when a PR was merged between two branches, then the commit IDs being compared were coming from two different branches. That was unintentional on my part though it does look like you can specify which branches the commits are coming from through some parameters.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: One commit can be on multiple branches simultaneously. Also, one commit can be on *no branch at all*. Do not attempt to treat branch names as being significant, because they aren't, and clones of the repository will have different branch names.